# How to get 11 bits representation from 8 bit (uint8_t) array in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, cryptography, private-key

I am trying to implement **BIP39 **standard in my project. Everything else if fine but I am badly stuck and I have searched Google and ChatGPT to the greatest depths, but no solution found.

I have vector <uint8_t> which is storing 33 bytes of entropy and checksum.

`vector <uint8_t> ent_cs; //have already put 256 bits (32 bytes) of entropy and 8 bits (1 byte) checksum`

I am trying to read this array as 11 bits representation (0 - 2,047) in `vector <uint16_t>` so I may assign a mnemonic word to each number which will be used as seed to to generate private key.

Also C++ does not have a native 11 bit integer data type

Thanks

I was expecting 24 eleven bit numbers between 0 and 2047 stored in uint16_t array / vector

Comment: The first 11 bits are easy to get: Get the first byte, then add the three lowest bits from the next byte (shifted up 8 bits and then bitwise-or'ed to the first byte). Then it becomes harder because you need to get the next five bits of the second byte, followed by the first six from the third. And so on. It might be easier if you put all the data into a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `std::bitset` (for some unknown reason) then create a function that can get an arbitrary bit from your original array. All that's needed is some basic arithmetic (division and modulo) to get the the byte where the single bit resides. Then some shifting and masking and more shifting to extract and return the bit.

Comment: "I have searched Google and ChatGPT" - don't rely on chat bots for writing code. They have no clue what they are doing, they just mash text together into a form that *looks* reasonable - there's no intelligence behind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code, it's designed for ease of understanding rather than ultimate efficiency

```
// 33 bytes is 24 11-bit numbers
for (size_t i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
{
    size_t offset = 11*i;
    size_t byte_offset = offset/8;
    unsigned bit_offset = offset%8;
    unsigned number = 0;
    size_t bits_copied = 0;
    if (bit_offset != 0)
    {
        // extract high bits from the first byte
        number += ent_cs[byte_offset] >> bit_offset;
        bits_copied += 8 - bit_offset;
        ++byte_offset;
        bit_offset = 0;
    }
    while (bits_copied < 11)
    {
        // extract whole byte
        number += ent_cs[byte_offset] << bits_copied;
        bits_copied += 8;
        ++byte_offset;
    }
    // remove any overflow (since bits_copied maybe greater than 11)
    number &= (1 << 11) - 1;
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Seems to be working. I am making some assumptions, specifically that lower bits and bytes in the vector are lower bits in the 11-bit numbers.

Comment: I have tried this solution but result is still not matching with the test vector. I think there is problem of endiness

Comment: @JammaDaud OK, I did say I was making assumptions. Some variation on this should work however.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this kind of conversion is to use an integer type to buffer bits from the input, generating output words whenever you've accumulated enough.

From the descriptions I found, it looks like BIP39 wants a big-endian conversion, so it would look like this:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> convert8sto11s(std::vector<uint8_t> &in) {
    uint32_t buf = 0;
    unsigned bits = 0;
    std::vector<uint16_t> out;
    for (uint8_t c : in) {
        buf = (buf<<8) | c;
        bits += 8;
        if (bits >= 11) {
            bits-=11;
            out.push_back((uint16_t)( (buf>>bits) & 2047 ));
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```